# Utilising $rootScope variables in directive template outside of ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to apply a conditional class to a nav bar directive template which sits ABOVE ng-view.

This is the basic set up on the index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <navigation-bar></navigation-bar>

    <div class="main-container" ng-view=""></div>
```

The navigation bar template is as follows:

```
<div class="nav-bar bg-primary">

    <div class="nav-bar-right-component">

        <button ng-click="toggleLock()" class="nav-bar-button lock-button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" ng-class="{'locked' : locked }"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is utilising the $rootScope to trigger events to show certain buttons such as the lock button. I am communicating the 'locked' variable between the controller and the $rootScope and it's all working fine. The only thing I need to do now is apply an ng-class using that 'locked' variable.

Is there any way of doing this without wrapping the navigation bar in a controller?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the controller as syntax of $rootScopte : `$root`

```
    <button ng-click="toggleLock()" class="nav-bar-button lock-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" ng-class="{'locked' : $root.locked }"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Wow so easy. Thanks, mate! You're a legend

Comment: I have to wait, but I will!